# Doctrine query builder in Symfony2 error: "Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

When I try to use this query:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('AcmeCommentoBundle:Commento');
                    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->select('DISTINCT p.user')
                            ->where('p.annuncio = :annuncio')
                            ->setParameter('annuncio', $annuncio)
                            ->getQuery();

                    $utenti = $query->getResult();
```

It returns this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 
    'user FROM Acme\CommentoBundle\Entity\Commento': 
     Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?  This url claims your error was fixed in version 2.2: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/w4V-ZLo3YH8

Comment: Could you edit your post and join the `Commento` entity along with your mapping file/annotations?

Comment: i want only make distinct user's field into commento's table

Answer (score 2):

solved

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->distinct('p.user')
                        ->where('p.annuncio = :annuncio')
                        ->setParameter('annuncio', $annuncio)
                        ->getQuery();
```

Comment: distinct() expects boolean parameter http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html#602-621